# OKHTTP is secure?

Tags: android, https, okhttp

I am building an android app that needs to log the user to our server and the connection needs to be secure (HTTPs). My question is, should I use OKHTTP library for this purpose?

I use the library to log a user as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private JSONObject responseJson;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    final JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject();
    try {
        myJson.put("udid","c376e418-da42-39fb-0000-d821f1fd2804");
        myJson.put("email","email
        myJson.put("password","password");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Your code goes here
                   String response =  post("https://ADDRESS/v1/auth", myJson.toString());
                    responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
                    String message = responseJson.getString("message");
                    String token = responseJson.getString("token");
                    Log.d(TAG,"Response message: " + message);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Response token: " + token);
                    Log.d("MainActivity",response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

}

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at certificate pinning if you want to lock it down further. This is dangerous because you can lock yourself out, bit it protects you against some security problems on the local device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I use OKHTTP library for this purpose?

OkHttp supports `https` URLs, as do most HTTP client libraries for Android.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still do not understand if the way I use it is secure (a.k.a. uses HTTPs post  to make the request)

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Thank you for the answer! I was hoping to hear that asI like how simple is to use the library and did not want to go through the hassle of implementing a HttpsURLConnection myself :p

Comment: I am using `OkHttp` in one of my projects which is related to real money. Trust me its working perfect. Although I have made some other customization to it as per my specific requirement.